# canopen_chain_node to read dictionary entries only

Tags: ros, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with two motors over the can bus. I have a can bus master and I would like to use the canopen_chain_node to only read values from the dictionary using the service getObject. For now I can do this without an additional master by calling the service init first and the calling getObject. The problem I have is that I have already a master on the bus, which is in charge of the NMT commands and to put the node in operational mode.
I thought that with the command for configuring the bus

**master_allocator: canopen::ExternalMaster::Allocator**

this would be possible.

The canopen_chain_node still changes the nodes to operational. So it is in conflict with the other master.

Question: Can I use the canopen_chain_node to hook into the can bus to just get dictionary entries using SDO respectively over the service getObject? I would like to get the motor temperature for instance and publish it using a topic, which can be reused later (graph).

Some of this was answered already in [**here**](https://answers.ros.org/question/275404/running-a-canopen-node-using-only-canopen_chain_node-and-canopen_master/), but it says also that it can accept another master in the bus respectively that another master can send the SYNC.

Second question: I cannot disable the SYNC in the canopen_chain_node by setting it to 0

**sync:
interval_ms: 10 # set to 0 to disable sync**

I get this error

**[ERROR] [1515076699.637053748]: Update interval  0 is invalid***

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278750/canopen_chain_node-to-read-dictionary-entries-only/) by [Edgar Carrasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/32511/edgar-carrasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Second question: I cannot disable the SYNC in the canopen_chain_node by setting it to 0

The SYNC is disabled, but you have to specify the update rate instead: `update_ms: ...`.
This rate determines how fast PDOs get read etc.

> canopen::ExternalMaster::Allocator

These plugins just set-up the SYNC, but not NMT.
This should support shared SYNCs, but not completely external masters.

> Can I use the canopen_chain_node to hook into the can bus to just get dictionary entries using SDO respectively over the service getObject? I would like to get the motor temperature for instance and publish it using a topic, which can be reused later (graph).

Currently there is no way to disable the NMT commands.
This would need some code modifications and a way to configure the layer (e.g. https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_canopen/issues/104).

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2018-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0